# Cannot install libhdf5-dev

Tags: apt, software-installation

Trying to install `pbh5-tools` on my Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine. I have encountered countless problems trying to get the program to install. I get the error:

```
In file included from /tmp/easy_install-BEtAkS/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/defs.c:287:0:
/tmp/easy_install-BEtAkS/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried downloading `libhdf5-dev` to solve this, but when I use `sudo apt-get libhdf5-dev`, I get this response.

```
Package libhdf5-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libhdf5-serial-dev 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2
  libhdf5-openmpi-dev 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2
  libhdf5-mpich-dev 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2
  libhdf5-lam-dev 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2
```

When I try installing the individual packages I get the same response:

```
E: Unable to locate package 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2
```

I downloaded the patch, configured it, made it, and installed it, but I still cant get it to work. Don't know what to do really.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 (not 18.04). I solved from [Carol Yuu's suggestion in Nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/jetson-nano-libhdf5-serial-dev-install-issue/75504/2).

Please try below command and install again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 
HW: Nvidia Jetson TX2